# How to suggest Cronjob redirect the console output to an url or to a script?

Tags: php, cron, console, laravel-5, scheduled-tasks

Got some schedules on Cron and need to save their output in the DB. Now it can be saved to a file or sended to an email. It is possible to send it somehow to an url or launch a prepaired script with it? 
I'm using Laravel scheduler. the commands are similar to this "* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1"

Comment: Please be more precise with your question, I just can't understand what you have and what you want to do...

Answer (score 0):

I've needed to get the generated output of a laravel cron Schedule and to save it in database. Laravel allow to insert/append output to a file or to senda it through an email. 
So, the solution is to insert the output to a file, then to use the `after` hook and read that file and , finally, to query the DB. The code is bellow.

```
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
protected $commands = [
    Commands\ReportExpiringResponseDate::class,
];

protected $outputFile = 'app/schedules.txt';

/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('ReportExpiringResponseDate')->weekly()->mondays()->wednesdays()
        ->sendOutputTo(storage_path($this->outputFile))
        ->after(function () {
            $this->saveLogs('ReportExpiringResponseDate');
        });
}

protected function saveLogs($scheduleName)
{
    $output = File::get(storage_path($this->outputFile));
    $logModel = (new ScheduleLog())->newInstance();
    $logData = [
        'schedule' => $scheduleName,
        'schedule_output' => $output
    ];
    if ($logModel->validate($logData)) {
        $logModel->fill($logData);
        $logModel->save();
    } else
        echo 'invalid data for logs';
}
```

}